# How do I can check an input file is compressed (ZIP) or not?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-design-studio

How do I can check an input file is compressed (ZIP) or not ?.

Is the solution to read the file info using "Get File Names" step and check the extension field ?

Comment: No. You identity files by their Magic Number, their first few bytes: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the "file" command if you're on Unix.
2. If not install cygwin and goto 1.

If this is related to your other question about conditionally reading different files then I would consider getting your files into a consistent format first. i.e. all compressed.